# Is there a DRY approach to applying a filter hash in a RAILS API controller index action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry, rails-api, json-api

According to the JSON API specification, we should use a filter query parmeter to filter our records in a controller. What the filter parameter actually is isn't really specified, but since it should be able to contain multiple criteria for searching, the obvious thing to do would be to use a hash.

The problem is, it seems like I'm repeating myself quite often in controller actions for different types of records.

Here's what things look like for just a filter that includes a list of ids (to get multiple specific records).

```
def index
  if params[:filter] and params[:filter][:id]
    ids = params[:filter][:id].split(",").map(&:to_i)
    videos = Video.find(ids)
  else
    videos = Video.all
  end
  render json: videos
end
```

For nested property checks, I guess I could use `fetch` or `andand` but it still doesn't look dry enough and I'm still doing the same thing across different controllers.

Is there a way I could make this look better and not repeat myself that much?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using concerns to just include the same code in multiple places, this seems like a good use for a service object.

```
class CollectionFilter
    def initialize(filters={})
        @filters = filters
    end

    def results
        model_class.find(ids)
    end

    def ids
        return [] unless @filters[:id]
        @filters[:id].split(",").map(&:to_i)
    end

    def model_class
        raise NotImplementedError
    end
end
```

You could write a generic `CollectionFilter` as above, then subclass to add functionality for specific use cases.

```
class VideoFilter < CollectionFilter
    def results
        super.where(name: name)
    end

    def name
        @filters[:name]
    end

    def model_class
        Video
    end
end
```

You would use this in your controller as below;

```
def index
    videos = VideoFilter.new(params[:filter]).results
    render json: videos
end
```

Comment: Much better than concerns approach

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on this, somewhat adapted from [Justin Weiss' method](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/):

```
# app/models/concerns/filterable.rb
module Filterable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def filter(params)
      return self.all unless params.key? :filter

      params[:filter].inject(self) do |query, (attribute, value)|
        query.where(attribute.to_sym => value) if value.present?
      end
    end
  end
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Filterable
end

# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users
  # GET /users?filter[attribute]=value
  def index
    @users = User.filter(filter_params)
  end

  private
    # Define which attributes can this model be filtered by
    def filter_params
      params.permit(filter: :username)
    end
end
```

You would then filter the results by issuing a `GET /users?filter[username]=joe`. This works with no filters (returns `User.all`) or filters that have no value (they are simply skipped) also.

The `filter` is there to comply with JSON-API. By having a model concern you keep your code DRY and only include it in whatever models you want to filter. I've also used strong params to enforce some kind protection against "the scary internet".

Of course you can customize this concern and make it support arrays as values for filters.

Comment: Prefer this method, a concern personally, but on trying I get error on the inject(self) part, otherwise this works all fine, (non filtered), but of course the idea is to have  filters? I got undefined method `inject' for #<ActionController::Parameters {"species"=>"cat"} permitted: true>  and with filter name, same error with an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **[Rails Concerns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)** to drying up ...

```
    ##================add common in app/models/concerns/common.rb
    module Common
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern  

      #  included do
      ##add common scopes /validations
      # end

      ##NOTE:add any instance method outside this module
      module ClassMethods
        def Find_using_filters (params)
          Rails.logger.info "calling class method in concern=======#{params}=="
          ##Do whatever you want with params now
          #you can even use switch case in case there are multiple models

        end
    end
  end

##======================include the concern in model
include Common

##=======================in your controller,call it directly    
 Image.Find_using_filters params
```